# Extract data from Excel cell like phone, email, address, ID etc

Tags: python, excel, vba, pandas

I have data as below in a single excel cell.

```
56.  MEMBER ID   2100343-219
ZAHID BROTHERS
MONTGOMERY BAZAR FAISALABAD TEL :   041-2646252
MOBILE : 0300-0321-9663180 FAX :
E-MAIL :
REP :   HAJI MUHAMMAD ABID
```

I am looking for ideas on how to extract each detail and form a proper excel table. I would prefer to use pandas. But Any viable solution is acceptable.

**EDIT**

I have used the following code to extract the required information. based on font and tag name (generated separately) in column 2.

```
Sub convert()
On Error Resume Next
Dim x As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim addressString
i = 1
For x = 2 To 37093
 If Sheet1.Cells(x, 1).Font.Name = "Arial Bold" Then
 i = i + 1
 Sheet2.Cells(i, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(x - 1, 1)
 Sheet2.Cells(i, 2) = Sheet1.Cells(x, 1)
 Else
  If Sheet1.Cells(x, 2) = "TEL " Then Sheet2.Cells(i, 3) = " " & Sheet1.Cells(x, 1)
  If Sheet1.Cells(x, 2) = "MOBILE " Then Sheet2.Cells(i, 4) = " " & Sheet1.Cells(x, 1)
  If Sheet1.Cells(x, 2) = "FAX " Then Sheet2.Cells(i, 5) = " " & Sheet1.Cells(x, 1)
  If Sheet1.Cells(x, 2) = "E-MAIL " Then Sheet2.Cells(i, 6) = " " & Sheet1.Cells(x, 1)
  If Sheet1.Cells(x, 2) = "REP " Then Sheet2.Cells(i, 7) = " " & Sheet1.Cells(x, 1)
  If Sheet1.Cells(x, 2) = "" Then Sheet2.Cells(i, 8) = Sheet2.Cells(i, 8) & " " & Sheet1.Cells(x, 1)
 End If
 
Next x
'TEL
'MOBILE
'FAX
'E-MAIL
'REP

End Sub
```

Comment: @Husnain It's very simple task and many answers already exists on stackoverflow, can you show us what you tried?

Comment: =REPLACE(MAX(IFERROR(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A19," ",""),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A19," ","")))),8)+0,"")),5,,"-") to extract phone number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a lot to solve the problem with an easy way. And I cam up with following solution.

```
Sub convert()
On Error Resume Next
Dim x As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim addressString
i = 1
For x = 2 To 37093
 If Sheet1.Cells(x, 1).Font.Name = "Arial Bold" Then
 i = i + 1
 Sheet2.Cells(i, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(x - 1, 1)
 Sheet2.Cells(i, 2) = Sheet1.Cells(x, 1)
 Else
  If Sheet1.Cells(x, 2) = "TEL " Then Sheet2.Cells(i, 3) = " " & Sheet1.Cells(x, 1)
  If Sheet1.Cells(x, 2) = "MOBILE " Then Sheet2.Cells(i, 4) = " " & Sheet1.Cells(x, 1)
  If Sheet1.Cells(x, 2) = "FAX " Then Sheet2.Cells(i, 5) = " " & Sheet1.Cells(x, 1)
  If Sheet1.Cells(x, 2) = "E-MAIL " Then Sheet2.Cells(i, 6) = " " & Sheet1.Cells(x, 1)
  If Sheet1.Cells(x, 2) = "REP " Then Sheet2.Cells(i, 7) = " " & Sheet1.Cells(x, 1)
  If Sheet1.Cells(x, 2) = "" Then Sheet2.Cells(i, 8) = Sheet2.Cells(i, 8) & " " & Sheet1.Cells(x, 1)
 End If
 
Next x
'TEL
'MOBILE
'FAX
'E-MAIL
'REP

End Sub
Sub setit()
Dim x As Long
For x = 2 To 37093
 If Sheet1.Cells(x, 1).Font.Name = "Arial Bold" Then Sheet1.Cells(x + 1, 1).Font.Name = "Arial"
   
Next x
End Sub
```

I set the font on Names row to one single font and put category type against each row. e.g if a row has "TEL" the column B must state it in "TEL" and similarly for other categories. The above formula worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try the next function, please:

```
Function ExtractDataFromCell(x As String) As Variant
  Dim arr As Variant, arrfin(3) As String, i As Long, start As Long, length As Long
  Dim strMembID As String, strTel As String, strMob As String, strRep As String

  arr = Split(x, vbLf)
  For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
    If i = 0 Then strMembID = Right(arr(i), Len(arr(i)) - InStrRev(arr(i), " "))
    If i = 2 Then strTel = Right(arr(i), Len(arr(i)) - InStrRev(arr(i), " "))
    If i = 3 Then
        start = InStr(arr(i), ":") + 1
        length = InStr(arr(i), " FAX") - start
        strMob = Mid(arr(i), start + 1, length):
    End If
    If i = 5 Then strREP = Right(arr(i), Len(arr(i)) - InStrRev(arr(i), "  ") - 1)
  Next i
  arrfin(0) = strMembID: arrfin(1) = strTel: arrfin(2) = strMob: arrfin(3) = strREP
  ExtractDataFromCell = arrfin
End Function
```

It can be called in this way:

```
Sub testExtractData()
Dim arr As Variant
 arr = ExtractDataFromCell(ActiveCell.Value)
 Debug.Print "MembID: " & arr(0)
 Debug.Print "Tel: " & arr(1)
 Debug.Print "Mob: " & arr(2)
 Debug.Print "REP: " & arr(3)
End Sub
```

Comment: @Husnain Iqbal: Did you find time to check the above function?

Comment: I am trying. I am a newbie

Comment: @Husnain Iqbal: Then, the simplest way of testing would be the next. Copy the above code (the function and the sub) in a standard module. Select a cell containing the described string to extract what you need and run `testExtractData()`. You can see the result in Immediate Window (Being in VBE, press `Ctrl + G`). After testing you can implement the function call in an iteration. If needed, after confirmation that the function works as you want, I can showing you how to do that...

Comment: Thank you for your help. The code generates the error on following line ```strMob = Mid(arr(i), start + 1, length):```

Comment: @Husnain Iqbal: Please, try testing the code on a cell having exact the content you put in your question. You can simply copy it form your question... If it works well on it, please post the string of the cell where it returns an error. I will try adapting it to deal with both situations. If possible, of course... You should post all possible string combinations...

Comment: It is working fine in sample data. It generates an error on 

``` 44.  MEMBER ID   2100254-170 MUHAMMAD SALEEM CLOTH MERCHANT 131 MAUHAMMADI MARKET RAIL BAZAR FAISALABAD
TEL :   041-2613100
MOBILE : 0300-9658093 FAX :
E-MAIL :
REP :   MUHAMMAD SALEEM```

Comment: @Husnain Iqbal: Please, edit your question and paste the second string (also some others if they not respect the same rule...). I cannot understand where is the lines ending...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your data is in a constant format, with 6 lines separated by `lineFeed`, and the data in the format you show, then you can do this using `Power Query` (available in Excel 2010+)

**Algorithm**

- Split columns by the `lf` delimiter into new rows
- Add an `Index` column and then an `Integer/Divide` column (by 6) to get a sequence of numbers where we can group the original (the sequence would be like `{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,...}`
- Group the original by the Integer/Divide column
- Extract each element, using various split functions and indices to return what we want.

In the example, I assumed the `lf`'s in your example in your comment were in the same place as the example shown.

**M Code**

*If you place a cursor in your column of data, and `Data-->Get & Transform-->From Table/Range`, it will create a Table, and label the column `Column1`. If you then paste the M-Code into the Advanced Editor in PQ, and change the Table name in Line 2 to whatever name was assigned your data, the Query should work.  You can explore the `Steps` area to understand what is going on*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("#(lf)", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Column1"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Column1", type text}}),

    //Add Index and Integer/Divide column for subsequent grouping
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Inserted Integer-Division" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Integer-Division", each Number.IntegerDivide([Index], 6), Int64.Type),
    
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted Integer-Division",{"Index"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Integer-Division"}, {{"GROUPED", each _, type table [Column1=nullable text, #"Integer-Division"=number]}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Integer-Division"}),
   
   //Extract each element into it's own column
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "SEQ", each Text.Split(Table.Column([GROUPED],"Column1"){0},"."){0}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Member ID", each Text.Trim(Text.Split(Table.Column([GROUPED],"Column1"){0},"MEMBER ID"){1})),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Name", each Table.Column([GROUPED],"Column1"){1}),
    #"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Address", each Text.Trim(Text.Split(Table.Column([GROUPED],"Column1"){2},"TEL"){0})),
    #"Added Custom4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom3", "Telephone", each Text.Trim(Text.Split(Table.Column([GROUPED],"Column1"){2},"TEL :"){1})),
    #"Added Custom5" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom4", "Mobile", each Text.Split(Text.Trim(Text.Split(Table.Column([GROUPED],"Column1"){3},":"){1})," "){0}),
    #"Added Custom6" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom5", "FAX", each Text.Trim(Text.Split(Table.Column([GROUPED],"Column1"){3},"FAX :"){1})),
    #"Added Custom7" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom6", "E-Mail", each Text.Trim(Text.Split(Table.Column([GROUPED],"Column1"){4},":"){1})),
    #"Added Custom8" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom7", "Rep", each Text.Trim(Text.Split(Table.Column([GROUPED],"Column1"){5},":"){1})),

    //Remove the Table column
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom8",{"GROUPED"})
in
    #"Removed Columns2"
```

**Source**

[image]

**Results**

[image]